# ReactJS, click on image and open link

Tags: reactjs, image, hyperlink

This feels like the dumbest question I've asked on SO. I can't figure out how to make an `img` tag clicable in React...

```
      <a className="App-link" href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
        <img src="facebook_ad.jpg" className="App-ad" alt="facebook ad" />
      </a>
```

Why the above code doesn't work? When I click on the img it just selects it.

Answer (score 0):

Ignore the question... I had my links wrapped in several divs and for some reason this was preventing the links to open. I removed those divs and now the link works.